# CPLEX with MATLAB using cplexmiqp

Tags: matlab, cplex

Hello my matlab code calls a cplexmiqp function to optimize a performance index.

The MATLAB code I am using calls a miqp function as from cplex
[v, fval, exitflag, output] = cplexmiqp(H, f, G, h, [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ctype );

I would be using the function "MIQPS_MATPOWER Mixed Integer Quadratic Program Solver for MATPOWER" from https://matpower.org/docs/ref/matpower6.0/miqps_cplex.html

I already have cplex optimization studio, but my question is where do I enter the inputs on the function?

For example using this inputs on the function:

```
        H = [   1003.1  4.3     6.3     5.9;
             4.3     2.2     2.1     3.9;
             6.3     2.1     3.5     4.8;
             5.9     3.9     4.8     10  ];
     c = zeros(4,1);
     A = [   1       1       1       1
          0.17    0.11    0.10    0.18    ];
     l = [1; 0.10];
     u = [1; Inf];       xmin = zeros(4,1);
     x0 = [1; 0; 0; 1];
     opt = struct('verbose', 2);
     [x, f, s, out, lambda] = miqps_cplex(H, c, A, l, u, xmin, [], x0, %%vtype,   opt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same question at

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1725610-using-cplex-with-matlab-newest-version/?s_tid=ans_lp_feed_leaf

The Matlab direct API in CPLEX was removed a few versions ago. And you can see more details in [detailed requirements for cplex](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/detailed-system-requirements-ibm-ilog-cplex-optimization-studio)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. My question is if that MATPOWER function miqps_cplex is supposed to go on cplex optimization studio as an OPL model to be called from MATLAB?

Comment: Yes indeed. Example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/callfrommatlab.M